# mostrar imagen base64 laravel y vuejs

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, laravel-5, vue.js, base64

estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen que está en el servidor, en la bd está guardada como string el código es el siguiente, si bien al traer la foto la obtengo en el objeto, no logro mostrarla, me trae el nombre con el cual me lo guarda en la base de datos, pero la guardo en el servidor, desde ahí recuperó la ruta y luego pretendo recuperar el nombre y asignarla después de `"img/profile/" + this.foto;` al concatenarle su nombre con `+this.foto`.

El Componente:

```
<template>
    <div class = "col-9 " >
        <div class = "col-sm" v-for = "oferta in ofertas": key = "oferta.id" >
            <img class = "img-circle": src = "getFoto()" alt = "" >
            <div class = "card-body" >
                <h5 class = "card-title" > {{ oferta.foto }} < /h5> 
                <p class = "card-text" > {{ oferta.precioNormal }} < /p>
                <!-- <a href="/usuarios/{{oferta.precioOferta}}" class="btn btn-primary">Ver mas </a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script >
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        ofertas: {},
        foto: ''
        ////data////
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getFoto() {
        return "img/profile/" + this.foto;
      },

      /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
      //cargo las ofertas 
      cargarOferta() {
        //pregunto con axios a la ruta del servidor de la API 
        axios.get("api/oferta").then(({
          data
        }) => (this.ofertas = data.data));
      }



    },

    created() {
      this.cargarOferta();
      Fire.$on('AfterCreate', () => {
        this.cargarOferta();
      })
      // setInterval(()=>this.cargarOferta(),3000);
    }
  } 
</script>
```

**el controlador donde traigo los datos(php) laravel :**

```
public function index()
    {
        return oferta::latest()->paginate(10);

    }
```

Me crea la ruta, pero el archivo me lo tira como `undefined`

[image: IMAGEN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás queriendo usar `this.foto` concatenado con `img/profile/` sin en ningún momento darle valor a `this.foto`, lo que tienes que hacer es recibir la oferta(que recorres en el v-for) como parámetro del getFoto() y concatenar el atributo foto de la oferta, quedando algo así:

```
  getFoto(oferta) {
        return "img/profile/" + oferta.foto;
  }
```

Sin embargo si la `oferta.foto` está en base64 no deberías concatenarlo con `img/profile` si no con `data:`.

Yo optaría por algo más sencillo, prescindiendo del método y usarlo directamente.

```
 <img class = "img-circle" :src="'data:' + oferta.foto" alt="">
```

Por último, un consejo, más de orden fíjate que el : lo usas con pegado al atributo de la izquierda, sin embargo el : modifica el atributo de la derecha, por los que siempre debe ir pegado al atributo, como mi ejemplo.